# html video fullscreen mode with typescript

Tags: html, video, typescript

could someone please tell me how to turn on fullscreen mode when using video tag? I am using following typescript:

```
var vid = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById('video1');
```

I would like to play video in fullscreen in window.onload event.

It seems typescript does not support requestFullscreen, or other "webkitFullscreen" mode. I search other questions on stackflow, and they seem bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add those to the interface:

```
// Add the missing definitions: 
interface HTMLVideoElement{
    requestFullscreen();
    webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

// now the following should work 
var vid = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById('video1');
if (vid.requestFullscreen){
    vid.requestFullscreen();
}else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen){
    vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but does not work. I am looking to play fullscreen video from window.onload event. If I add a button on the page and add hook up the code you mentioned, then it works.
`code`
<button onclick="goFullscreen('video1'); return false">Click Me To Go Fullscreen! (For real)</button>

Also, IE10 does not seem to support any of these modes. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this then

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");  

if (elem.requestFullscreen) {  
  elem.requestFullscreen();   
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();  
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {  
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();  
}
```

For documentation [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)

Comment: I tried this but does not work. I am looking to play fullscreen video from window.onload event. If I add a button on the page and add hook up the code you mentioned, then it works. code <button onclick="goFullscreen('video1'); return false">Click Me To Go Fullscreen! (For real)</button> Also, IE10 does not seem to support any of these modes. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but does not work.

I am looking to play fullscreen video from window.onload event. If I add a button on the page and add hook up the code you mentioned, then it works. code Click Me To Go Fullscreen!

Also, IE10 does not seem to support any of these modes. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a video in full screen requires a synchronous user interaction, i.e. the user must click on a button, and only then the click handler can request full screen mode.